# What is the output of a simulation of quantum particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations, computational-physics

1. When physicists simulate a quantum system, what is the output of such computation?
   Is it the probability wave function of the system?
2. What if the system consists of enough particles to be considered macroscopic? 
   For example a simulation of a cell as a system of atoms and elementary particles (A cell consists of about 10<sup>14</sup> atoms, so this question is still hypothetical).

Comment: 1. The output is what one has been asking for (this could be some simple experimentally observable quantity such as magnetization or something else such as the wave function). -- 2. What should be in that case? You need to specify your question better. -- Lastly, why is this tagged "quantum-computer"?

Comment: There is a good question lurking within this post, but it's not clear and probably too broad as currently written. Can you edit this to be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. When physicists simulate a quantum system, what is the output of such computation? Is it the probability wave function of the system?

This depends on the simulation, but in general it will either be the full $n$-body system's wavefunction, or an approximation to it, using e.g. few-body states. If your simulation does not have access to the wavefunction at some level, it can't simulate the quantum aspects of whatever physical scenario you're dealing with.

Of course, when making plots for actual physical observables this tends to be analysed in terms of the corresponding probabilities instead of probability amplitudes, but in essentially all situations you have access to non-measurable wavefunction components, should you so desire.

> 2. What if the system consists of enough particles to be considered macroscopic? For example a simulation of a cell as a system of atoms and elementary particles (A cell consists of about $10^{14}$ atoms, so this question is still hypothetical).

Full $n$-body simulations are *nowhere* near the stage where they can tackle this, and there is no expectation that classical computers will ever be able to handle it.

> Assuming the collapse of the wave function is a real and objective phenomenon that happens in macroscopic systems and is not well understood (is that correct?), and that a system the size of a cell is big enough to involve collapse of the wave function, then does that not prevent us from simulating it as the collection of particles it consists of, as a quantum system?

Computer simulations will only do what you tell them to. Even if you had a magic computer that can simulate the unitary quantum evolution of a living cell, it will only ever simulate unitary evolution because that's what you've programmed it with. It will never spontaneously collapse or decohere unless you program it in.

Computer simulations will not help us solve the [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem), and in fact the problem is not so much to do with the system's size or complexity - this is why it's still an open problem.

Comment: *Full $n$ -body simulations are nowhere near the stage where they can tackle this...* Is the QM $n$-body problem that difficult? I mean, there was a [trillion-body gravitational](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4406) code run a few years ago, what's the trouble (computationally speaking) that is hindering the QM $10^{12}$-body problem?

Comment: @Kyle The scaling is competely different. If you have n bodies, each with a Hilbert space of dimension d, the total dimension of the space your dynamics takes place in its $d^n$, as opposed to $dn$ for a classical simulation. You'll appreciate the consequences, I believe.

Comment: That might make things difficult. Perhaps we should consult Deep Thought or Earth for assistance.

Comment: You wrote "if you had a magic computer that can simulate the unitary quantum evolution of a living cell", and I ask, will there not be in such a case a discrepancy between the simulation and the living cell?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is standard practice to plot the probability density function (not the wavefunction), in the output of such simulations.
2. In this case, it is more practical to use simulations in the statistical mechanics regime. For eg. to simulate particles in a one dimensional lattice chain, you may wish to use the Ising model and observe the number of particles at each lattice site after a certain time interval and in this way track the evolution of the system. The point I am trying to make is that QM is seldom used when so many particles are involved; you observe the "large scale" behaviour of the particles in those situations which can be described by simpler models and equations than QM.